# Random item from Parse database

Tags: ios, random, parse-platform

I want a random object from my database, but it doesn't work.

This is how my database looks like:

```
PFObject *master = [[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"items"] getFirstObject];
int maxIndex = [master objectForKey:@"index"];

NSLog(@"MaxIndex = %d", maxIndex);

// Randomly pick an index in the range maxIndex.
int randomIndex = arc4random() % maxIndex;

// Get the card with that particular index.
PFQuery *cardQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"items"];
[cardQuery whereKey:@"index" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomIndex]];
PFObject *card = [cardQuery getFirstObject];

NSLog(@"The next item is picked: %@", card);
label.text = card;
```

[image]

What's the problem?
The problem is that it outputs maxIndex as 19, even while there are only 2 items in the database. And no results matched the query.

Comment: What's not working? Please be specific.

Comment: Sorry. It outputs maxIndex as 19, even while there are only 2 items in the database. And no results matched the query.

Comment: Please include the details in your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`getFirstObject` returns the first (and same) item each time. This probably results in your `maxIndex` being set to 1 each time. This means that your `randomIndex` will also be 1, giving you the same card each time.

Try using `countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` as your first query, then pick a random number less than the count and finally retrieve your random item.

Something along the lines of the following, but be sure to handle errors appropriately:

```
PFQuery *countQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"items"];
[countQuery countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
    int randomIndex = arc4random() % number;

    // Get the card with that particular index.
    PFQuery *cardQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"items"];
    [cardQuery whereKey:@"index" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomIndex]];
    [cardQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"The next item is picked: %@", object);
    }];
}];
```

p.s. as to why you maxIndex is 19, you are casting an `NSNumber` to an int. Rather, use this: `int maxIndex = [[master objectForKey:@"index"] intValue]`. But still, the better way is above.

Comment: Thanks! How should I do that?

Comment: Also, be sure you are performing your Parse queries using the "InBackground" methods so that you don't lock up your UI.

Comment: And post a new question when you get to the `label.text = card;` line of code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Abit late to the party. But here is a swift 4 generic version for getting random object.

1. Count objects
2. Get random index
3. Create new query
4. Set skip to value
5. Add limit 1 and return

   `extension PFQuery where PFGenericObject == PFObject {
       func getRandomObject(callback: @escaping (PFObject?) -> Void) {
           let className = parseClassName
           countObjectsInBackground { (number, error) in
               let newQuery = PFQuery(className: className)
               let randomIndex = Int(arc4random() % UInt32(number))
               newQuery.skip = randomIndex
               newQuery.limit = 1
               newQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
                   callback(objects?.first)
               })
           }
       }`
   }